# How do you create a dummy for a specific year/quarter for time series data?

Tags: r

I have created a time series data with help of the ts() function. The data is quarterly and ranges from 1980Q1-2013Q1. It consists of 5 variables: consumption, oil, income, rate and wealth. I want to create a dummy from the variable "consumption", that is equal to 1 for the third quarter of 2008, and 0 for everything else.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you show few lines of your data using `dput`

Comment: How do I use the function properly? I just get a lot of numbers and it looks very unstructured. Tried to narrow it down with n=10 but it still looks unstructured.

Comment: I thought I did it incorrectly, that why I deleted it.

Comment: Can you check whether `time(ts1)` works and if so post the `head(time(ts1))`

Comment: [1] 1980.25 1980.50 1980.75 1981.00 1981.25 1981.50

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `Consumption` `cbind(ts1, dummy=(time(ts1)==2008.75 & ts1[,'Consumption']==1)+0)`

Comment: When doing regression analysis in R, creating dummies is often unnecessary for we can specify them as `I(x)` inside `lm`. If you are  doing panel regression with individual/time effect, setting `effect="individual/time/twoways"` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
  ts2 <- cbind(ts1, dummy=(time(ts1)==2008.75 & ts1[,'Consumption']==1)+0)
```

Comment: Says that it could not find function "index".

Comment: @NikaNika Can you show a small example data with codes about how you created the ts object.

Comment: I imported it from an excel file where the first contains name of variables and then columns the values for each variable. I imported it into R using read.csv2. Then ts(data, frequency=4, start=c(1980,1)). I logged values with log() function and then differentiated it with diff()

Comment: @NikaNika I tried your way and the `index(ts1)` gives `[1] 1980.00 1980.25 1980.50` for 3 rows of data.